# Firefox SDK simple-storage and Firefox Sync

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently converting a Chrome extension into a Firefox add-on and would appreciate to replicate the chrome.storage.sync feature.

However, I cannot manage to find whether the data stored by a Firefox add-on using [simple-storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) will be automatically synced whenever a user of the add-on is signed into [Firefox Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync).

Given that all the pieces of data stored via the latter method can be found in the user profile, I presume it will... as long as the add-on is available at https://addons.mozilla.org ?

Any information on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's easily testable if you have access to two computers or an Android phone/tablet ([simple storage is a compatible with Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development#Module_Compatibility).

Comment: Preference and addon syncing is not available in Firefox for Android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`simple-storage` is not synced. But you can sync it with little effort.

The trick it to store the `storage` object, it is serializable by definition, as a string preference and tell to the sync service to synchronize it.

Lets name that preference `syncstorage` and mark it as synchronizable.

```js
var self = require("sdk/self");
var prefs = require("sdk/preferences/service");
prefs.set("services.sync.prefs.sync.extensions." + self.id + ".syncstorage", true);
```

When storing something to `simple-storage` reflect the change to `syncstorage`.

```js
var sp = require("sdk/simple-prefs");
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
sp.prefs["syncstorage"] = JSON.stringify(ss.storage);
```

For the opposite effect watch `syncstorage` for changes

```js
sp.on("syncstorage", function(prefname){
  ss.storage = JSON.parse(sp.prefs["syncstorage"]);
})
```

Last but not least, It would nice and perhaps mandatory to sync only with the explicit consent of the user.

Comment: Thanks @paa, I have this partially working in https://github.com/anaran/JotFirefox/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sp+on+syncstorage+function+prefname. I can see local pref changes and changes from other addon installation come in this way, but I don's get successful merges. Instead I get
 `Sync.Engine.Prefs WARN DATA LOSS: Both local and remote changes to record: LONG_ID_VALUE`

Comment: @stackunderflow this is just a hack to make `simple-storage` synchronizable. Resolving merge conflicts is far beyond that. If your `simple-storage` object is large and/or complex, try to synchronize it in smaller isolated chunks. If this doesn't make a difference then describe the exact steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks paa for the clarification.

Meanwhile I was able to get merging sync working between linux and windows xp with following [issue fix](https://github.com/anaran/JotFirefox/issues/3).

Too bad preferences are not synced in Firefox for Android.