# Firefox Add-on SDK equivalent to Chrome's chrome.storage.sync?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to port a Chrome extension to Firefox. The extension uses Chrome's 
[`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync) API to store user preferences in the browser and sync them to other browsers using Chrome Sync.

Is there an equivalent API in the Firefox Add-on SDK? I know about the [`simple-storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) API but that only stores data locally and will not sync it to other browsers (or will it?)

Comment: Currently we don't have a sync thing. I think all preferences are syncd right now, if the users chooses to do so.

Comment: @Noitidart Tx. The preferences I was asking about are custom to my Firefox add-on. Therefore, they are not synced across devices unless I explicitly implement the solution described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318396/firefox-sdk-simple-storage-and-firefox-sync .

Comment: Thanks for sharing that solution!